# None of the configured nodes are availableException

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have elasticsearch server installed and running on localhost
I'm trying to connect to elasticsearch and create index 
I'm using elasticsearch-5.3.2 version

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build();
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9300)));        
        System.out.println( "Started ES client" );
```

here is elasticsearch.yml file

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: elasticsearch
#
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
 # Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
#
# Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# Set a custom port for HTTP:
#
http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
 # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of master-eligible nodes / 2 + 1):
#
#discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
#
# For more information, consult the zen discovery module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
#
# Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
#
#gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
# For more information, consult the gateway module documentation.
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Require explicit names when deleting indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

I have this error

```
    Found an exception -> None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{TbtN0u5YR6W1ngZGOMWNJA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]
    NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{TbtN0u5YR6W1ngZGOMWNJA}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:344)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:242)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:366)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:404)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:393)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesAdmin.execute(AbstractClient.java:1231)
        at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient$IndicesA
dmin.create(AbstractClient.java:1358)
```

thanks!

Comment: Can you provide elasticsearch server logs?

Answer (score 0):

I have a version 1.0.1 of elasticsearch installed previously and i remove it and install the version 5.3.2
here is elasticsearch.log file:

```
[2017-05-02T10:55:33,584][WARN ][o.e.t.n.Netty4Transport  ] [tASzAvl] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0x036b7f79, L:/127.0.0.1:9300 - R:/127.0.0.1:46318]], closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [1.0.1] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1323) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:74) ~[transport-netty4-5.3.2.jar:5.3.2]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:293) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:280) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:396) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) [netty-codec-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:341) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:363) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:349) [netty-transport-4.1.7.Final.jar:4.1.7.Final]
```